# How to create a Decisecond(0.1second) function that can use in the code?

Tags: unity, c#, mathematics

I create a circular object and pivot the minute and second pointer on the middle of the object as below.
[image]
Below is the code I use.

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

public class Pivot_minute : MonoBehaviour
{
    long x;

    void Update()
    { //1complete revolution for minute pointer=3600000millisecond
        x = DateTime.Now.Minute*60*1000+DateTime.Now.Second*1000+DateTime.Now.Millisecond;
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, -(x*0.0001f));
        
    }
}

using System;
using UnityEngine;

public class Pivot_second : MonoBehaviour
{
    long x;

    void Update()
    {// 1 complete revolution for second pointer=60000millisecond,then x millisecond=x/60000*360degree
        x = (DateTime.Now.Second*1000+DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, -x*0.006f);
    }
}
```

As tested, taking the millisecond precision is definitely showing a smoother pointer movement(not discrete movement) compare to the code below using "second" accuracy as calculation.

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

public class Pivot_second : MonoBehaviour
{
    int x;

    void Update()
    {// 1 complete revolution for second pointer=60 second, then x second= x/60*360 degree
        x = (DateTime.Now.Second);
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, -x*6);
   
    }
}
```

Now I want to test the Decisecond(0.1second) accuracy to find out at this precision, can I still distinguish between the discrete movement and continuous movement of the pointer? Search through internet and so far do not have any luck.

Comment: A decisecond is just 100 milliseconds. Presumably you tried taking your millisecond code and dividing `x` by 100?

Comment: My mistake, suppose to say that how to produce a code that have the precision in between second and 100 milliseconds, example 500 milliseconds? The rotation is showing discrete movement in second but how about 500,600 millisecond and etc.

Comment: So you tried dividing by 500, 600, etc?

Comment: No. Sorry I do not understand how that going to help or even how to do that? As an example,DateTime.Now.Second output 1 second changes for every second, so at time=1.2second, it still output 1 second,1.3second also output as 1 second, only at time=2second, it output 2. so the resolution is 1 second and just I convert this resolution to rotational resolution. While I was hoping to find a code like "DateTime.Now.HalfMilliSecond" that change every 500millisecond.

Comment: I see, you mean round up to the required decimal place in each step? I think I can try that out later. Thank for the idea.

Comment: DateTime.Now.Second gives you the Seconds *component* of a time value. For 12:05:03, it returns the "03"; that's why it's giving the impression of the 1-second resolution, as you've described. However, the resolution is much higher. You need to change your approach a bit. What you can do instead is subtract two DateTime-s to get a TimeSpan (e.g., store some initial DateTime, then subtract DateTime.Now from that on every update). Then you can use the TotalSeconds (or TotalMilliseconds) property - a floating point value - to get the total time elapsed, then calculate the offset for each handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

  public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
 {
   long y;
   long x;
   long z;
   void Update()
   {
    y = DateTime.Now.Millisecond;
    if(y<500)
    {
        x = 0;
    }

    if(y>500&&y<999)
    {
        x = 500;
    }

    z = (DateTime.Now.Second * 1000 + x);
    transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, -z * 0.006f);
}
```

}

Thank for the idea, got it already just define the roundup boundary using if statement, then can define any precision I want in between second and millisecond.